# In Angular 4 How to re-inject a component created from the template

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am building an app using Angular 4, and I would like to remove and re-insert a DOM element using a custom structural directive.

The template with the custom structural directive looks like this.

```
    <div class="header-nav" *showIn="'xs'">
        <a class="nav-link nav-icon"
           [class.active]="isSearchFormOpen | async"
           (click)="toggleSearchForm()">
            <clr-icon
                [attr.shape]="(isSearchFormOpen | async) ? 'zoom-out' : 'zoom-in'">
            </clr-icon>
        </a>
    </div>
```

and the 'showIn' structural directive does the following.

```
@Input() set showIn(target: string) {
    console.log(this.templateRef);
    this.breakPoint.subscribe((breakPoint) => {
        if (target === breakPoint) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.remove();
        }
    })
};
```

The 'breakPoint' is a value returned every time the window gets resized, and depending on whether this value matches the input value of the directive, I would like to inject or eject the DOM element.

The issue is when the element is injected again after it's been removed from the view, the 'clr-icon' element is injected without the attribute binding I set up initially ('[attr.shape]="(isSearchFormOpen | async) ? 'zoom-out' : 'zoom-in'"), making the element itself invisible. It's only after I explicitly click inside the window that this attribute binding kicks in, making the element visible again.

How can I reinsert the DOM element without losing all property & attribute bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an embedded view and store the reference to it. Then just insert or detach it. Something like this:

```
view = this.templateRef.createEmbeddedView(null);

@Input() set showIn(target: string) {
    console.log(this.templateRef);
    this.breakPoint.subscribe((breakPoint) => {
        if (target === breakPoint) {
            this.viewContainer.insert(this.view);
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.detach();
        }
    })
};
```

This solution is much more performant because it is simply attaches/removes the view DOM nodes to the host DOM node instead of creating and destroying the view each time which destroys/creates DOM nodes relevant for the view.

Comment: I somehow made it work by using ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges(), but I think this is a much better solution. Thank you very much.